# Using HTTPS proxy with requests fails when schema is present

Tags: python, python-requests

I have to use an HTTPS proxy to connect to a service and pass client side certificates.

The [docs](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/user/advanced/#proxies) demonstrate using the schema in the value (e.g. `https://`), but this throws::

```
s = requests.Session()
s.proxies.update({'https': 'https://host.ip.com:port'})
s.cert = (CRT_FILE, KEY_FILE)
s.verify = False
r = s.get(URL)

# (stack trace)...
# ValueError: check_hostname needs a SSL context with either CERT_OPTIONAL or CERT_REQURIED
```

Excluding the schema works:

```
# ...
s.proxies.update({'https': 'host.ip.com:port'})
# ...
r = s.get(URL)
r.status_code
# 200
```

Why does the request fail when the schema is included? Is there a standard for this key/value pairing for proxies?

*Note*: environment is on another system, cannot copy/paste the whole stack trace.